# How can i open a folder using python?

Tags: python, directory

I've tried reading through the other answered similar questions, yet still can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```
file=open("Crawl","r")
cont=file.read()
file.close
print(cont)
```

It's as simple as that. Both the folder and python are on the desktop which explains why there isn't a directory to it. I did try opening .txt and .png files and that did work, but it seems I can't open folders?

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Crawl'

Comment: Are you running your script with administrative privileges?

Comment: Are you asking "How do I open and read from each file in a directory, one after the other?"? Try iterating over the filenames given by `os.walk` or `os.listdir`. If that's not what you want, please give more detail. What do you expect the output for `print(open("Crawl").read())` to be when Crawl is a directory?

Comment: @DenisCallau yes i do have administrative privileges

Comment: @Kevin alright thanks i'll try that right now!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to open "Crawl" as a file. It's a folder, and you can't treat a Windows folder as if it were a file.

Comment: So should i try importing os and using os.listdir to open a folder?

Comment: Well, I don't really know what you planned to do with the folder after you opened it, but if you wan't to examine all the files in the folder then that is an easy way to do it.